# Use Standard Apex Method UserInfo.getUserEmail() in Custom Metadata

Tags: apex, custom-metadata, user-management

I want to move below collections into Custom Metadata

```
private static Set<String> validAddresesForGoogle = new Set<String>{
            'info@google.com',
            'info2@google.com',
            'careers@google.com'
            UserInfo.getUserEmail()
    };

private static Set<String> validAddresesForYoutube = new Set<String>{
            'info@youtube.com',
            'info2@youtube.com',
            'info3@youtube.com'
            UserInfo.getUserEmail()
    };
```

I have built Custom Metadata for the same using two fields **Address Type** - Picklist(Google, Youtube) and **Address** and created multiple records.

The place where I am falling is moving **UserInfo.getUserEmail()** into the custom Metadata. Is there any way to accomplish this? I want to keep this value in Metadata only even if it can be handled in Apex.

Comment: By definition, Custom Metadata is a static. What you're shown in your question clearly runs as the logged in user, which means that attempting to move this into a custom metadata record would mean either using a single value, or having to somehow many a record for each user. Some context as to why you are needing to move this out of Apex would help use to answer this or provide a different solution.

Comment: An obvious solution is to have a placeholder in the custom metadata that the code or flow using the metadata looks for and substitutes with the contextual user's email address.

Comment: this seems a good idea

Answer (score 0):

We can have an additional **Boolean field** checked to True for the Current User's mail Address and false for the rest of the records

| Name | Address | Is User Address(Boolean) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A_01 | {will be blank} | Checked |

And In Apex we can check for

```
if(Is_User_Address__c == true) {
     custometadata__c.Address__c = UserInfo.getUserEmail();
}
```

And use this Address__c field value in Apex